# store a mysql array records in session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, session

I have a school web application ..
I want to get all the student name on the log_in.php pages in $_SESSION['allStudent']
for retrieve on further page...

here is my log in .php pages content

```
    include("connect.php");
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
$id=$_REQUEST['userName'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['password'];

$sel=mysql_query("select * from login_detail where USERNAME='$id' AND  PASSWORD='$pass'")or die(mysql_error());
if($arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{

    if(($id==$arr['USERNAME']) && ($pass==$arr['PASSWORD']))
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_personal";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if($result)
        {
            $_SESSION['allStudent']['']= mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }
        header("location: viewPages/common/main.php?active=dashboard");
    }
     }
      else
     {
echo "<script>alert('please enter the correct  id and password');</script>";
   }
    }
```

and retrieve into main page
this is my main pages

```
           {
           //designed Part
          }
        <?php
    if(isset($_SESION['allStudent']))
    {
    echo "------------------------------------------<br>";
    echo "Student Name--------------------------- DOB<br>";
    echo "------------------------------------------<br>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($_SESSION['allStudent']))
    {   

    echo $row['STUDENT_NAME']." --------------".$row['DOB']."<br>";

    }
        }
        else
         {
       echo "No result Found";
         }  
        ?>
```

and this is my table

```
       DB NAME : testssdb
       Table Name : student_personal

       `SR_NUMBER` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `STUDENT_NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       `GENDER` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `DOB` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
       `RELIGION` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `MAILING_ADDRESS` text NOT NULL,
       `TELEPHONE_NO` varchar(22) default NULL,
       `MOBILE_NO` varchar(25) default NULL,
      `EMAIL` varchar(30) default NULL,
      `PERMANENT_ADDRESS` text,
      `MOTHER_TONGUE` varchar(30) default NULL,
      `CATEGORY` int(11) default NULL,
      `STATUS` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
      `REG_DATE` date NOT NULL,
      `FIRST_NAME` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `LAST_NAME` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`SR_NUMBER`)
```

Here $student = $firstname.$lastName;
So basically i want to store all student records on log in and anyneed of student,i do not want to intrect with the database. only use of session i get the student information

Comment: You store the result of `mysql_fetch_array` in your session and when accessing you use `mysql_fetch_array` again?! You have to add the resource to your session. But don't do it. Fetch all students from the database use `mysql_fetch_array` for every row and then you can add it to your session.

Comment: Also you have some typos in your code. Is this your real code? There is no variable `$_SESION`.

Comment: sorry due to typing mistake i write SESION now i correct it but steel i fetch the problem and also remove the `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_start();

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;

    $_SESSION['record'][$_SESSION['count']] = array();

    $query //retrive ur data here
    $result set of ur query
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    $_SESSION['record'][$_SESSION['count']]['SR_NUMBER'] = $row["SR_NUMBER"];
    $_SESSION['record'][$_SESSION['count']]['STUDENT_NAME'] = $row["STUDENT_NAME"];
    $_SESSION['record'][$_SESSION['count']]['GENDER'] = $row["GENDER"];
    $_SESSION['record'][$_SESSION['count']]['DOB'] = $row['DOB'];
    ...// and go on

    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
    }

    foreach($_SESSION['record'] as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value['SR_NUMBER'];
        echo $value['STUDENT_NAME'];
        echo $value['GENDER'];
        echo $value['DOB'];
        ....
    }
```

Comment: thnk you very much for solve my problm ... @Ashihttp://stackoverflow.com/users/2663434/ashishsh

Comment: you can fetch this records where u want and by using $_SESSION['count'] u can get any index value too..welx...

Comment: i already fetch the value by using for loop... again thnx.
Many people mark me negative for this question..